# Not getting images in document directory folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to get images in document directory folder.

I am using this code.

```
  NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

  for(int i=0;i<[imagepath count];i++)
  {
  NSString* documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];

  NSURL *img = [NSURL URLWithString:[imagepath objectAtIndex:i]];

  //here imagepath is array in that i get the url of image.
  //here when i print the img data i got url from where i have to get images.


  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:img options:NSDataReadingMapped error:nil];

  //here when i put NSLog i get the null.

  NSString *fullImagePath1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png",i]];

 [newreturnImage addObject:fullImagePath1];

 [data writeToFile:fullImagePath1 options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
 }
```

I can't get images in document directory folder.

What could be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code,

```
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDirectory,@"myimage.png"];
    UIImage *cellImage=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    UIImageView *temp=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    temp.image=cellImage;
    [myView addSubview:temp];
    [temp release];
```

Updated :

```
NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];
UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:myData];
```

Comment: I get the images from url,and i have to convert that image so that i have to take NSData.

Comment: so u need to fetch image from an URL and u are not able to achieve it ?

Comment: as mention in my code  nsusrl *img in that i get the url but in nsdata get the null value.

Answer (score 1):

This link may help you. In the link **James Webster** has provided an excellent method which suits your requirement. If this does not help you. The code below that would definitely work for you as it works for me.

[How save images in home directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362436/how-save-images-in-home-directory)

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

  for(int i=0;i<[imagepath count];i++)
  {
  NSString* documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];

  NSURL *img = [NSURL URLWithString:[imagepath objectAtIndex:i]];

  NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:img];

  NSString *fullImagePath1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png",i]];

 [newreturnImage addObject:fullImagePath1];

 [data writeToFile:fullImagePath1 options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: Anyways.. this may help someone else if not you.